# Subcategory is not showing in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm new to opencart.

I have created a category and a subcategory through admin panel. When I tried to add new product to the sub category, it does not shows the subcategory I have created in 'category' section on Links tab. So, that the product displaying under main category.

How can I solve the issue?

My category -> Mobiles, subcategory -> test. The dropdown in Links tab for `'category'` only showing `'Mobiles'`, not Mobiles > test. So, I can only add product to `'Mobiles'`. But, I want to add products under `'test'`.

Comment: just begin to tap `test` and it will shows in dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

edit: admin/controller/catalog/category.php

You can increase limit

Code: Select all

```
'limit'       => 5
```